# Original error: Could not get focusPackageAndActivity

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium

I have been getting the below error while running automated tests on Android 13 with Appium 1.8.1
Does anyone know what could be wrong?

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. 
Original error: Cannot start the 'com.myapp.test.phaseone' application.
Original error: **Could not get focusPackageAndActivity**. 
Original error: Could not parse activity from dumpsys (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

This error does not exist with the latest appium version. Due to some limitations, I have to stick to appium 1.8.1